# 2 Level of dynamic routing in next.js

Tags: next.js, url-routing

I am new to `next.js`. I want to ask how to achieve two level of dynamic routing in next.js?

My url is `http://localhost:3000/company/[slug1]/[slug2]`

In the `next.js` official documentation I got only one level nesting routing.

I want to 2 level routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create directory structure like this

```
pages/
 └─ company/
     └─ [slug1]/
         └─ [slug2].js
```

To access segments on the client side

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export function Component() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { slug1, slug2 } = router.query;
  // ...
}
```

Or if on the server side

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
  const { slug1, slug2 } = ctx.params;
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks brother. This is working for me. I can not voting b'coz I opened account recently.

Comment: You can accept the solution buddy, by clicking on the **tick**.
Glad to know that it helped you.

Comment: Thanks brother for giving me this information.

Comment: what about app directory?